# Why I'm getting ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS in my application hosted on OPENSHIFT?

Tags: tomcat, openshift

I've followed the steps from this article: http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=2241, and everything worked ok (I've managed to upload my application and it's running).
After some days, when I accessed it, I've started to get "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" error using any browser (using HTTP or HTTPS). I've stopped the application but the error remains (!), anyone have any ideas of what could be going on?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check that your .htaccess doesn't have redirects enabled. Also do you have any type of cache enabled? Last but not least I would check your url link in your database to make sure the right url is in there.

Comment: where is located .htaccess file? I couldn't find it

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, check that you have cleared your browser cache for your application domain.  It's possible you error condition sent a cacheable redirect and your browser is remembering it.  Has happened to me a few times.

Comment: I will answer myself: The problem was that my startup script had problems and It wasn't finishing, so the apache server, running in openshift, was creating the redirects, in order to "wait" that my startup script finishes. The solution was to replace my scripts with the one proposed in this post: https://github.com/openshift/openshift-tomcat-quickstart